# Word describing one who is not aware of their own actions?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I'm reading a book and writing an essay where I need to describe the main character's personality traits, but I can't quite find the word for "unaware of one's actions."

Comment: You mean like sleepwalking? Or just absent-minded?

Comment: Oblivious?  Self-unaware?

Comment: human? psychopathic?

Comment: maybe unconscious?

Comment: I agree with cornbread ninja that _oblivious_ (or _obliviousness_) is a good choice if your intention is to indicate a person's unawareness of the effect that his or her actions have on others, potential dangers that those actions may expose him or her to, or indeed any consequences related those actions. If the point is to describe a state of complete unconsciousness of the actions themselves, _somnambulist_ or _zombie-like_ might work.

Comment: For context, what's the name of the book?  This may help with an answer.

Comment: The question is not very clearly stated, and single-word-requests need a sample sentence. The sample sentence should make clear what part of speech (adjective? verb?) you're looking for, an ideally provide a sense of the *register*. That is, are you looking for a clinical or scientific word? A colloquialism?

Answer (score 1):

*incognizant* is probably what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The casual tone may not be appropriate for your essay, but *clueless* has become popular for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Oblivious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oblivious)

adjective
1.
unmindful; unconscious; unaware (usually followed by of or to):
She was oblivious of his admiration.
2.
forgetful; without remembrance or memory:
oblivious of my former failure.
3.
Archaic. inducing forgetfulness.